# Is there a way to remove the name from the mac menu bar

Tags: macos, mac

In Mountain Lion it's showing my name next to the clock (upper right hand corner of the screen). Is there anyway to turn that off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on your login name, in the menu bar.
2. Click on `Users & Groups Preferences`.
3. Click the padlock if it's showing as locked, to allow changes, and enter your credentials when prompted.
4. Click `Login Options`.
5. Unselect `Show fast user switching menu as 'xxx'`.
6. Close the System Preferences window.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Was that added in a later version of Mountain Lion or did I just miss it?

Comment: Nope, it's been there since Snow Leopard at least.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can also hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key and drag it off the menu bar while still holding it. That will  remove it from the menu bar view.

If you want the user-switching (name) element back, you can tick the *Show fast-user switching menu* and it will return to it's original position.

*Works on Lion and Mountain Lion.*